# Building Windows phone app using the command line or shell

Tags: svn, batch-file, windows-phone-8, command-line, msbuild

My windows phone 8 application is successfully built from compilation button of Visual Studio. Also I can built the application using the command line successfully with the following commands.

```
cd /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

MSBuild [Project Local Path]/[Project Name].sln /t:build
```

I commit the code to svn. Now I need to fully automate the build process. 
Type in command line with the syntax:

```
cd /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Then type in command line with the syntax:

```
MSBuild [Project Repository Path]/[Project Name].sln /t:build
```

Following error was occurred

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
```

If anyone knows how to solve this(How to build a windows phone 8 project from SVN) or any plug-in to build the project in the svn repository, I'm pleased to hear.

Comment: Does Project Repository path contain spaces? If so, put quotes around `[Project Repository Path]/[Project Name].sln`

Comment: No spaces in the Project Repostory path.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you don't know how to read go back to school! THE FILE IS NOT THERE! Just make sure that the file exist! Or do this code:

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set net_framework=%cd%
cd [Project Repository Path]
"%net_framework%\MSBuild.exe" [Project Name].sln /t:build
```